# C# - Invoke Event Outside Of Declaring Class

Tags: c#, events, compiler-construction, derived-class

I have an event in class `Alice` that I want to raise inside of a derived class `Bob`:

```
public class Alice
{
    public event Action<object> ValueChanged;
}

public class Bob : Alice
{
    public void method1(Alice bigAlice)
    {
        // raise ValueChanged event
        // or
        // raise ValueChanged event on bigAlice
    }
}
```

Compiler error says I can use only `+=` and `-=` if I'm not in the declaring class of the event. How can I fire that event nevertheless from code of Bob ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could expose a protected method to invoke it:

```
public class Alice {
  public event Action<object> ValueChanged;

  protected void RaiseValueChanged(object o) {
    if (ValueChanged != null) {
      ValueChanged(o);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Race condition: http://broadcast.oreilly.com/2010/09/understanding-c-raising-events.html

Comment: It's possible that the invocation list of `ValueChanged` might change after the null check but prior to the event invocation (possibly leading to a nullref exception). Take a copy and work with that instead. IMO threads and events make fairly unhappy partners anyway, but taking a copy is idiomatic.

Answer (score 8):

Events cannot be raised anywhere other than the declaring class.

Create a protected method in your base class that raises the event and call it from your subclass.

Comment: Because I still have Java in my mind I just notice that I can't call a protected method on a foreign object although it is from class `Alice`. Is there some help for that ?

Comment: @mini-me: You'll be able to call the protected method from a _subclass_ of `Alice` (such as the `Bob` class you posted). If you want _other_ classes that aren't subclasses of `Alice` to fire the event, then you need to make the firing event `public`.

Answer (score 3):

You could do it like this, make a protected method that fires the event and call it from the Bob method. 
EDIT: Removed the problem with possible race condition, as suggested by @spender

```
    public class Alice
    {
        public event Action<object> ValueChanged;
        protected void OnValueChanged(object arg)
        {
            Action<object> temp = ValueChanged;
            if (temp != null)
            {
                temp (arg);
            }
        }
    }

    public class Bob : Alice
    {
        public void method1()
        {
            object o = null;
            OnValueChanged(o);
        }
    }
```